What is the reason behind using Substitution
Using launch.py files allows to use python scripting and integrate some logic in the launch file. However this can only be done in the OpaqueFunction(function,args). Could someone explain why is it not possible to access or modify variables in the generate_launch_description().
Some code to make it more explicit :
def launch_topic_tools(context, *args, **kwargs):
    actions = []

    namespace = LaunchConfiguration('namespace').perform(context)
    twist_relay = Node(
        package='topic_tools',
        executable='relay_field',
        name='twist_relay',
        arguments=[
            namespace+'/'+'mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel',
            namespace+'/'+'mobile_base_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped',
            'geometry_msgs/Twist',
            '{linear: m.twist.linear, angular: m.twist.angular}',
        ],
    )

    actions.append(twist_relay)
    return actions

def generate_launch_description():
    # Create the launch description and populate
    ld = LaunchDescription()

    namespace = LaunchConfiguration('namespace')
    ld.add_action(PushRosNamespace(namespace))
    ld.add_action(OpaqueFunction(function=launch_topic_tools))

    return ld

